# Webview upload sending notification

Tags: android, upload, webview, contact-form

I have an android app that leads to a webpage which contains a contact-form with file upload. Ones the user clicks upload, selects an image, fills a form and finally clicks send.... the app seizes for few seconds (or minutes) depending upon upload file size and internet speed.

What I intent to do is show a dialog box with running bars (I don't know the right term) saying "sending..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is to edit the webpage itself and simply show an HTML dialog or use the WebView JavaScript Interface (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)).
If you can't edit the webpage, you could probably use something like the following showing the dialog only for the specific URI. (not tested)

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     //called if progress changed => page is loading
     if (uri == "http://example.org") {
         //show dialog
     }         
   }
 });
```

Comment: I have access to HTML will probably do the first thing. Thanks.